# Anraten vs. raten vs. zuraten vs. empfehlen

Tags: word-usage, difference, verb-choice, verb-usage

*Anraten* vs. *raten* vs. *zuraten* vs. *empfehlen* — all these verbs mean *to advise*, *to recomend*. But anyway, is there any difference between these verbs? Are there any places, where I can use the one, but not the other?

Comment: 1. Does *erraten* really mean advise? 2. Do you want (5 \choose 2)=10 comparisons?

Comment: You are right, `erraten` is to guess. The question is updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- raten: more advise than recommend. With a bit of certainty, “I know what is best, do X”. (Be sure to use a dative object (whom do you advise, wem rätst du etwas) or it can mean guess.)
- empfehlen: recommend. More subjective than “raten”, ”I like Y best, try that”.
- anraten, zuraten: sound old-fashioned. Seldom used nowadays.

Also

- beraten: counsel, advise. “Tell me what you want and I’ll tell you how“.